# Get object reference not set to instance

Tags: c#, oop

```
    [DataContract]
        [Serializable]
        public class WSAccount
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Pin { get; set; }        
        }

 [DataContract]
    [Serializable]
    public class WSUser
    {
       [DataMember]
        public WSAccount wsAccount { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public bool IsValidUser { get; set; }
    }
```

Get an error  while doing

```
WSUser user = new WSUser();
 user.wsAccount.AccountNumber = userNameresponse.account.ID;
```

but resolved when

```
 WSUser user = new WSUser();
 user.wsAccount = new WSAccount();
 user.wsAccount.AccountNumber = userNameresponse.account.ID;
```

do i need to instantiate child class WSAccount ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do.

That's because your default constructor (if not redefined, and it's not) uses default values for every field or auto-property it has. Meaning, every int gets '0' as a value, and every reference type (wsAccount) - null.

So you do have to instantiate wsAccount property to a correct object, otherwise it's null.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need `wsAccount` to be a valid `WSAccount` (e.g. not `null`) if you want to access any properties or methods of it. By default, it is initialized to `null` which is the default for any object reference.

You can of course initialize it inside the constructor of `WSUser`, such as:

```
public WSUser() {
    wsAccount = new WSAccount();
}
```

Most likely, you can't or don't want to do that though, since you may want a single `WSAccount` to be used by multiple other instances (of other classes). Either pass the account as a parameter to the `WSUser` constructor or let the caller set it after construction. The former is probably preferable, since your constructor can do some sanity checks on the input and you can't forget to set the account after constructing (since the constructor forces you to pass one beforehand).

Answer (score 1):

All types have their default values:

- reference types (including string) => null
- value types => (int=> 0, float=> 0 , Guid => Guid.Empty, etc..)

That is why you need to explicitly instantiate your WSAccount class.
You could also instantiate WSAccount in the constructor of WSUser

```
public WSUser()
{
  this.wsAccount = new WSAccount();
}
```

Or you could lazy load wsAccount

```
private WSAccount _wsAccount;

public WSAccount WsAccount
{
  get 
  { 
    if (_wsAccount==null)
      _wsAccount= new WSAccount();
    return _wsAccount;
  }
  set { _wsAccount = value }            
}
```

Finally,

You can implement a lazy loaded variable using the `Lazy<T>` available from C# 4.0

However, during deserialization the deserializer will invoke, under the hood, the default constructor and then set the property accordingly, hence doing this:

```
WSUser user = new WSUser();
user.wsAccount = new WSAccount();
user.wsAccount.AccountNumber = <value>
```